# <nav> not sizing properly in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, nav, distortion

So my `nav` works great in Chrome and Firefox but Internet Explorer is squishing it when you size down in the desktop layout. Here's the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#top"><img class="scale-with-grid arrow" src="assets/images/ColorArrowLogo.svg" alt="Home button"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#UX"><img class="scale-with-grid UX" src="assets/images/UX.svg" alt="User experience"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#UI"><img class="scale-with-grid UI" src="assets/images/UI.svg" alt="User interface"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#front-end"><img class="scale-with-grid front-end" src="assets/images/FE.svg"  alt="Front end development"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

...and the CSS:

```
img.scale-with-grid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) {


    nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        width: 7%;
        max-width: 81px;
        margin: 1.7% 1.7%;
    }


    nav ul li {
        margin: 0 0 15% 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
    }

}
```

If you need the rest of the site's code let me know, I just put up what appeared to be relevant.

Comment: Have you tried using absolute height like pixels rather than relative height such as percent like you have?

Comment: Unfortunatally I need a percent in order for my layout to work. I'm in IE11 by the way.

Answer (score -1):

`<nav>` tag is not supported in ie 8.0 or older
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp

Comment: Technically no, but it will work fine if you use a shiv, or in some cases you just simply need to declare it in your css as a block element: nav {display: block}

Comment: Also for the love of god, please don't ever use w3schools as a reference in an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks Andrew, but can i ask you what's the problem with w3schools?